# What is the 6th Gen (2018) iPad's Touch Delivery Rate?

Tags: ipad

Apple hasn't updated their [display documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html) for the new iPad yet. Is the 6th Gen (2018) iPad's Touch Delivery Rate 60Hz or 120Hz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 60Hz. It is aimed for students. And It is a budget friendly iPad when compared with the iPad Pro.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: @SteveMoser
Yes "It even lacks the iPad Pro’s ProMotion tech, which boosts the display refresh rate up from the roughly 60Hz found on a device like this to an impressive 120Hz" Source - [MacWorld](https://www.macworld.com/article/3267994/iphone-ipad/97-inch-ipad-2018-review.html)

Comment: I’d second this answer. There isn’t any official source but it seems likely that Apple wouldn’t have gone without mentioning it if this wasn’t the case. +1 for the answer.

Comment: However, as I have mentioned in my last comment, MacWorld article states it is not 120Hz. And It would not be possible to make an iPad which has less refresh than the last iPad (60Hz). Thus, it is in 60Hz.